# Using the web2py DAL with temp tables

Tags: python, data-access-layer, web2py

I'm trying to execute some raw SQL against a temp table through the web2py DAL, but my results are all returning None.

Here's the full function:

```
def test():

    db_test = DAL('mysql://root:root@localhost/test')

    sql = """CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp LIKE people;
    INSERT INTO tmp SELECT * FROM people;
    INSERT INTO tmp SELECT * FROM people;
    SELECT * FROM tmp;"""

    results = db_test.executesql(sql)
```

Obviously the SQL is a simplification, but running the same SQL in a SQL pane returns the correct results. What do I need to do to get the DAL working with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot execute multiple statements in one `executesql` call *I suspect*; web2py uses the [DBAPI 2.0](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) `.execute()` call for sending these to the backend database and that usually supports only single statements:

```
db_test = DAL('mysql://root:root@localhost/test')

sqlddl = """CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp LIKE people;
INSERT INTO tmp SELECT * FROM people;
INSERT INTO tmp SELECT * FROM people;"""

for statement in sqlddl.split(';'):
    db_test.executesql(statement.strip())

sqlselect = "SELECT * FROM tmp;"
results = db_test.executesql(sqlselect)
```

Comment: thanks, but I just tried this with the same result- still returning `None`.

Comment: I must say that I am very wary of web2py; for one, it'll do a `fetchall()` regardless of result set size. This will easily cause memory problems if your result set is large enough.

Comment: Thanks for the update- the mulitiple execution may have been the problem, so I solved that by rolling it into a stored procedure.

Comment: btw- as for being wary of web2py, not sure why- It's a great framework with a robust DAL. Your point about the `fetchall()` isn't something I know about, but seems a child-safety detail rather than something to dismiss a framework over.

Comment: @Yarin: Well, it reinvents a lot of wheels as well in a monolithic codebase.

Comment: Yes, but you don't have to attach all the wheels on your own or get them each serviced at a different service station. And some of them run faster and handle better than existing wheels. :-)